# How to get Fn + Home/End bind work on i3-gaps?

Tags: linux, archlinux, window-managers

I'm using i3-gaps WM on my Arch Linux. I wrote a simple Python script to change my brightness, but Fn + Home or Fn + End bindings aren't working. However, Fn button itself works just fine, I made a test bind just for the single Fn key and it worked. Also, the Python script works just fine when I bind it to something else (I tried F11 and F10 keys), so I literally have no idea what the problem is.

My i3 config:

```
bindsym XF86WakeUp+Home exec --no-startup-id python ~/scripts/brightness.py up #  Raise brightness
bindsym XF86WakeUp+End exec --no-startup-id python ~/scripts/brightness.py down # Lower brightness
```

As mentioned before, Fn key itself works fine, so this line works:

```
bindsym XF86WakeUp exec --no-startup-id python ~/scripts/brightness.py up
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your problem is that the "Home" key is not named after "Home".

To quote i3's [reference card](https://i3wm.org/docs/refcard.html):

> Throughout this guide, the i3 logo will be used to refer to the configured modifier. This is the `Alt` key (Mod1) by default, with `⌘` (Mod4) being a popular alternative.

Meaning that your "Home" key should be named after "Mod4". That's how I do it on my i3wm.

Alternatively, you can use the program `xev` from an X11-Bound Terminal.
Type the key you are looking for and search for the `KeyPress` or `KeyRelease` event sections within the terminal output. You should see something like `(keysym XYZ, ZYX)` You can use the `XYZ` (just after `keysym`) into your i3 configuration file.

Comment: I've tried using xev and my Home button named 'Home', I also compared other binds that work and they key names in xev, and all of them match.
I guess we have a misunderstanding, but by Home button I mean 'Home and End' pair of buttons that move the cursor, not the 'windows logo' key (which is named after Mod4 and works fine)

Comment: @drakeen0 Indeed, sorry in a German keybord "Home" is named "POS1" .... Have you tried without `--no-startup-id` ? How do you change the brightness in your python script. Does your normal user has access to the thing you use in there ? Sometime it's just a permission issue if you are sure that the keys are working. Do you mind showing us/me how it looks like ? How do you test your script ?

Comment: I change my brightness by changing 'sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness' file value (it ranges from 1 to 3000):

def up(cur):
    system('echo {0} > {1}'.format(cur + 25, brightness_path))
#and the same thing for lowering

--no-startup-id makes no change. Yes, user has access to it. I tried some other binds and it seems that I can't bind Fn + *any other key*, but I can replace Fn with smth else. Currently I use 'HOME' button + Home/End and it works. Seems like it's some weird i3 bug. Again, Fn itself works. I tried binding it to lower/upper brightness and it worked.